# I was reading "cambridge IELTS" books and I had a problem in the meaning of a sentence

Tags: verbs, ielts

I was reading "cambridge IELTS" books and I had a problem in the meaning of a sentence. the sentence is : 
(I may have to call somebody out)
 what does "may have to call" mean?

Answer (score 1):

> I may have **to call somebody out**

*Call somebody out* is the idiomatic phrase, not *may have to call*.

It has a couple of common meanings:

> • Summon someone to deal with an emergency or to do repairs
>
> • Draw critical attention to someone’s unacceptable actions or
>   behaviour

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/call-someone-out

Which meaning is intended should be obvious from the context in which it is used.

The second meaning above is marked as North American, so make of that what you will. Also, this meaning usually specifies what the person is being called-out for, such as 'I called him out for his constant swearing'.

Comment: I agree with this but I think it is necessary to draw attention to  the idiom 'to have to' as well as the idiom 'to call somebody out'.